# OBIEE: What's the way to create an action link between an analysis in one subject area to an analysis in different subject area?

Tags: obiee, drilldown

I am using OBIEE to create reports on the data that I have.
I have one use case where I want to enable `drill down` action from an analysis in one subject area to an analysis of two different subject area.
Is there a way to do that? 
P.S I tried creating filter - isPrompted and using action links, 
but it is not working. 

**Possible Problems:**

1. OBIEE can't map proper column names from parent to child analysis.

2. It's not possible to create a drill down action-link between analysis of different subject areas.

Please shed some light on this.
Couldn't find relevant information on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Drilling down will work if your column name is the same, both in the parent and the child (the name includes the presentation table name). It doesn't matter which subject area it is.

For example, if you have a field "Customer Info"."CUST_ID" in two Subject Areas `subarea1` and `subarea2`, the Action Link will work off of this field. If your presentation table name "Customer Info" is different in each subject area, then use an alias or make table name same.

You can also set a presentation variable and reference it in your child report's filter.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could also have problems if the context of the parent and child analyses are different.

Ensure that the contexts of both the parent and the child report's subject areas are the same, by including the same Facts in the child as the parent has. 
This will force the child to have the desired granularity.

The child report's grain will naturally be different, but the Subject area(s) and dimensions used in the child report may force an incorrect context, which could result in "No Results".

Please see [this resource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/fusionapps.1111/e14849/dacsubjectarea.htm) for understanding context in subject areas.